# Running Legacy 16bit Dos application on 64 bit SBC board on Free dos 1.2

Tags: freedos, 16-bit

Running Legacy 16bit Dos application on 64 bit SBC board on Free dos 1.2. The application works with an older SBC board on FD1.2 but fails to load system status screen on a new SBC board. There is another board that should communication with the SBC board via backplane. Any suggestion?

I've already tried DOSBox, WIN10 32 with NTVDM, Vdos, Dosbox-X. Non of these the worked with old nor current SBC board.